# What does the phrase "mock up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the expression "source real products, mock up your space, and bring it to life with AR" in the following sentence:

[Morpholio Board lets you source real products, **mock up** your space, and
bring it to life with AR.](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/morpholio-board/id1475021279)

For more context, here is another excerpt from the same text:

> Have an eye for interior design? It’s easier than ever to realize your
>   vision, from finding the perfect chairs to picking a wall color to
>   complement them....Start by dragging product images onto your blank
>   board. There are thousands in the app, everything from bath tiles to
>   light fixtures to furniture by manufacturers like Knoll, Blu Dot, and
>   Poliform, as well as retailers like Design Within Reach. You can also
>   import your own images.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A mock-up is "a model or replica of a machine or structure, used for instructional or experimental purposes"

It is saying you can use this interior design software to make a quick model of whatever interior design project you're working on.

Comment: "Mock up" means to build a model; "source real products" means to use pictures of commercially available things instead of standardized images or drawings; "AR" stands for "augmented reality," which is Apple hype for the software that's supposed to enhance images to make them look more "real."

Comment: Notice that the verb “to mock” has a number of meanings. “Mock-up” comes from the less common, or even outdated, meaning, “to mimic, imitate, or counterfeit“.  “Mock” is more commonly used in the developed sense of “ridicule”, or even “defiance”, and so learners might be confused by the phrasal verb “mock up” which relies on a different meaning.